# Events from same list in two Sencha Touch navigation views

Tags: sencha-touch

I have a list:

```
Ext.define('my.view.ProgramList', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
  xtype: 'programlist',
  ...
}
```

I would like this list to be the starting point for two navigation views:

```
Ext.define("my.view.ProgramNavigationView", {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'programnavigationview',
  ...
  items: [{
    xtype: 'programlist',
    itemId: 'programlist'
  }]
}

Ext.define("my.view.FacebookNavigationView", {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'facebooknavigationview',
  ...
  items: [{
    xtype: 'programlist',
    itemId: 'programlist'
  }]
}
```

Question: How do I handle tap events in the controller and deal with the two separately? In my controller I have:

```
refs: {
    programlist: 'programlist',
    facebooknavigationview: 'facebooknavigationview',
    programnavigationview: 'programnavigationview', ...
},
```

I have tried this:

```
control: {
  programlist: {
    initialize: 'initProgramData'
  },
  facebooknavigationview: {
    itemtap: 'showFacebookGroup'
  },
  programnavigationview: {
    itemtap: 'showProgramData'
  },
```

hoping the itemtap would bubble up and I can deal with differently in the facebooknavigationview vs. the programnavigationview, but it doesn't. I can put the itemtap in the programlist and it fires, but then I can't tell the difference between the two navigation views; I don't know if I can search the hierarchy, but that seems sort of... ugly. What am I missing?

Comment: Is it too much to create a separate list for `facebooknavigationview`?

Comment: I could do that ... not very DRY though.

Comment: Haha True. So what do you mean by you can't tell the difference between the two nav views? Is it that the data being displayed is the same for both nav views?

Comment: Keeping two different itemIds and refs would work, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ref that use the parent to help differentiate where the taps are coming from for example if you have the following views:

```
Ext.define("my.view.ProgramNavigationView", {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'programnavigationview',
  ...
  items: [{
    xtype: 'programlist',
    itemId: 'programlist'
  }]
}

Ext.define("my.view.FacebookNavigationView", {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'facebooknavigationview',
  ...
  items: [{
    xtype: 'programlist',
    itemId: 'programlist'
  }]
}
```

you could use the following refs:

```
refs: {
    programlist: 'programlist',
    facebooknavigationview: 'facebooknavigationview programlist',
    programnavigationview: 'programnavigationview programlist', ...
},
control: {
  programlist: {
    initialize: 'initProgramData'
  },
  facebooknavigationview: {
    itemtap: 'showFacebookGroup'
  },
  programnavigationview: {
    itemtap: 'showProgramData'
  },
```

Now the item taps are listening when they are displayed inside of the parent views.